# Can ADF pipelines be called from External Schedule?

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell

Is it possible to call ADF pipelines from external schedulers? We have an enterprise scheduler, and want to integrate ADF scheduler with the same. Is it possible?
Is it good design to call a Python/PowerShell script from the enterprise scheduler, which will trigger the adf pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure they can! In fact, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers) explicitly tell how:

> You can manually run your pipeline by using one of the following methods:
>
> - .NET SDK
> - Azure PowerShell module
> - REST API
> - Python SDK